# MYSQL Counting amount of rows (if exists) from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this question makes no sense, sorry for that, best way I can explain it is visually.

My tables are:
category, comment, member and review.

I have a query which selects information from the 3 latest reviews

```
SELECT  `reviewID` ,  `reviewTitle` ,  `reviewContent` ,  `reviewDate` ,  `gameRating` ,  `reviewImage` ,  `firstName` ,  `lastName` ,  `categoryName` 
FROM member
INNER JOIN review
USING ( memberID ) 
INNER JOIN category
USING ( categoryID ) 
ORDER BY  `reviewDate` DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

[result](http://puu.sh/kF8NM/e83f3e0312.png)

Each review is assigned a reviewID, comments are also assigned a reviewID to determine which review the comment is for. I want to also count the amount of comments per review. Comments tables includes:

```
commentID  reviewID  memberID commentDate commentContent
```

I've tried

```
SELECT `reviewID`, `reviewTitle`, `reviewContent`, `reviewDate`, `gameRating`, `reviewImage`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `categoryName`, count(commentID) AS comments
FROM member INNER JOIN
     review
     USING (memberID) INNER JOIN
     category
     USING (categoryID) INNER JOIN
     comment USING (reviewID)
ORDER BY `reviewDate` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

But it only gives this [result](http://puu.sh/kF90w/9c4f907d23.png)
which is correct as that review has 2 comments, but the other 2 reviews have 0 comments so I assume it should just return null instead of not displaying the other reviews all together? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need `left join`s:

```
SELECT member.*, count(commentID) AS comments
FROM member LEFT JOIN
     review
     USING (memberID) LEFT JOIN
     category
     USING (categoryID) LEFT JOIN
     comment
     USING (reviewID)
GROUP BY memberId
ORDER BY `reviewDate` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

You need a `GROUP BY`, but you should also remove all the non-member columns.